# jquery modal dialog form

Tags: jquery

Can someone please help

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form

I want onclick event instead of button click , that is i want a link to appear create new user instead of button .

Please help

Answer (score 3):

First add a link to the html

```
<a id='myLink' href='#'>Click Me</a>
```

Second set the onclick function to the link

```
$( "#myLink" ).click(function() {
                $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
        });
```

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much benone . You are just great . Thanks once again

Comment: @jim: You should really accept his answer by clicking the checkmark icon!